# how to mirror the richtextbox control in two screens [Edited]

Tags: c#, image-processing, richtextbox, desktop-application

i'm trying to mirror my Richtextbox to another screen in Pictuerbox. actually i did that but my issue is (Lets to make my question clear say that we have 2 **screens** (Screen A and Screen B).

I want to show the Richtextbox in Screen B. As when i open a start menu in screen A it mustn't be shown in screen B. All i want in my program is to mirror the richtextbox as a control not the whole screen.
is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it works and i dont have time to try it but i think you need to create 2 controls. By the 1st one you check the .textChanged() and when it is triggered you update the second textbox.

Example (pseudo code):

```
TextboxA;
TextboxB;

If TextboxA.TextChanged()
{
  TextboxB.Text() = TextboxA.Text();
}
```

Maybe there is an better way, but this is the way i should try when i make it for my self. Hope it helps you.

Comment: Please edit the question to include this crucial requirement!!

Comment: Ok, now i understand what you mean, sorry i cant help you with this :(

Answer (score 0):

What you describe sound like two over network connected applications. I would suggest to look for a chat network app. There are lots of examples in the net. On one side you will have a server and on the other side a client. Then you transfer your text char by char or word by word over the network.